# How to count duplicate value in google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a table record customer buy commodity per day,

customer maybe buy it one time per day, or two times per day.

```
    Date    Customer    spent
2022/5/31   Customer A  200
2022/5/31   Customer B  100
2022/5/31   Customer C  160
2022/5/31   Customer D  50
2022/5/30   Customer A  50
2022/5/30   Customer F  50
2022/5/30   Customer B  40
2022/5/30   Customer C  50
2022/5/30   Customer D  400
2022/5/30   Customer E  90
2022/5/29   Customer F  60
2022/5/29   Customer F  100
2022/5/29   Customer D  200
2022/5/29   Customer C  50
2022/5/29   Customer B  30.03
2022/5/29   Customer A  50
```

I would like to find out is this customer's first time or second time or third time come to shop to buy things.

For example, there are 4 customers(A, B, C, D) buy things first time at 2022/5/29.
And 1 customer(F) buy things first time and second time at 2022/5/29.

```
    Hope Result     
Date       First Time   Second Time   Third Time
2022/5/31        0           0           4
2022/5/30        1           4           1
2022/5/29        5           1           0
```

[sample google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oxhWMVPt-GziG10agob-xbiNYfKrZVFK9ro0Pj7tn6Y/edit#gid=705106706)

Many thanks.

Comment: what if customer skips day 2 and returns on day 3? how this should be counted?

Comment: should be count on day 3